# Is something depicted in art or within art?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am writing about certain paintings and the content depicted on the canvas. Which proposition should I use: `in` or `within`?

```
"... depicted in paintings"
```

or

```
"... depicted within paintings"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either "in" or "within" can be used, with slight differences depending on whether you're talking of painting as a medium or a physical space. In art history, "in" seems more common, particularly when talking about style or technique, although "within" can be used to emphasise ideas of containment or closure within a geometrical space.

If you're talking about painterly technique or the artist capturing something on canvas, then "in" is common: "the collagelike organization of shallow space in paintings by Picasso, Gris and Stuart Davis" ([Art in America](https://www.artnews.com/art-in-america/aia-reviews/laurie-fendrich-60783/)), "Rousseau's vision and his unself-conscious techniques inspired similar effects in paintings by Picasso, Paul Klee, Andre Derain, and Raoul Dufy." ([MOMA](https://assets.moma.org/documents/moma_catalogue_249_300063172.pdf))

If it's something contained within the pictorial space of the painting (particular spatial arrangements, such as what is inside the frame), "within" is often used, e.g. "a painting within a painting", or "secrets hidden within paintings" ([Oxford Student](https://www.oxfordstudent.com/2019/11/16/the-secrets-hidden-within-paintings/)). Here you are emphasising the geometrical arrangement rather than the technique.